# SQL Server group by date, time between status

Tags: sql-server, join, query, group-by, date-format

I have a table that looks like the following:

```
id_usr          dt_event                    Sequence
0000001         2015-08-01 14:57:21.737     1
0000001         2015-08-06 15:34:21.920     2
0000001         2015-08-07 09:26:24.427     3
0000001         2015-08-09 09:30:06.247     4
0000002         2015-08-03 17:39:02.027     1
0000002         2015-08-05 16:34:17.990     2
0000002         2015-08-10 20:37:26.043     3
0000003         2015-09-05 13:41:43.767     1
0000003         2015-09-06 13:34:23.440     2
0000003         2015-09-10 14:57:21.737     3
0000003         2015-09-17 15:34:21.920     4
```

and I'm trying to transpose the data to find how long between sequence times records have been ageing, such that the result would look like:

```
id_usr      1-2(days)       2-3(days)     3-4(days)
0000001     5               1             2
0000002     2               5             NULL
0000003     1               4             7
```

How can I write a query that returns in a similar format using SQL Server 2017?

Comment: Please either provide sample data that matches your results, or results that match your sample data. I am currently assuming that you want to identify the gap between rows (in days) for each user, which should be relatively simple using LAG or LEAD, but seeing the output you need for each set of inputs is very helpful. For example, the first two rows in your sample data have a gap of 5 days, 1 hour or so. Where would that fit in your output scheme?

Comment: LEAD() to calculate the gap, PIVOT to "transpose".